# Displaying HTML content in a field

Tags: html, json, blackberry

I'm getting a JSON response from the server. Inside that JSON string I have HTML content which I need to display in a field. How do I do this?

Comment: explain "field"? how does this relate to blackberry?

Comment: I want to display the HTML String i am getting from the server on my Blackberry app screen...

Comment: as in a HTML field on the blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? What kind of field?
If it's a div or p

```
var yourContent = "";
$(".selector").html(yourContent);
```

If it's textbox use

```
$(".selector").val(yourContent);
```

That's of course if you using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON result is say:

```
({
name: 'John'
})
```

We grab it and operate on it like so:

```
$.getJSON("http://yourjsonresource",
        function(data){
            $('h1#foo').text( data.name );
        }
);
```